# Chern Weil theory-user friendly guide

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I would like to learn basics about Chern Weil theory but I don't know from which place I should start. I'm after rather basic differential geometry course and have some background in algebraic topology (ordinary homology and cohomology, characteristic classes: Chern, Pontraigin, Stiefel Whitney) but I would like to see geometrical interpretation of the theory of characteristic classes. I will be grateful for any sugestions

Answer (score 0):

Connection, curvature and cohomology, Vol 1 and Vol 2 Academic Press 1972 by Greub Halperin Vanstone is a very good reference.